# Display data from JSON to TextView in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have a json file with this values:

```
[
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "abacus",
    "type": "math device",

  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "beaker",
    "type": "science device",
  }
]
```

What I want is to display these values in my html file I'm thinking of how can I use the ng-repeat but I can't seem to find out how can I do it. Can you please help me? Any help would be appreciated. This is my html section on where i want to display the json:

```
<div class="form-group" >
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
            ID:
        </label>                                                  
        <div class="col-md-8">                                           
            <input type="text" name="regular" class="form-control" ng-model="id">
        </div>
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
            Name:
        </label>                                                  
        <div class="col-md-8">                                           
            <input type="text" name="regular" class="form-control" ng-model="name">
        </div>
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
            Type:
        </label>                                                  
        <div class="col-md-8">                                           
            <input type="text" name="regular" class="form-control" ng-model="type">
        </div>
            <br><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/suj7gfgk/).

HTML

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="item in data">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
    ID:
  </label>                                                  
  <div class="col-md-8">                                           
    <input type="text" name="regular" class="form-control" ng-model="item.id">
  </div>
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
    Name:
  </label>                                                  
  <div class="col-md-8">                                           
    <input type="text" name="regular" class="form-control" ng-model="item.name">
  </div>
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
    Type:
  </label>                                                  
  <div class="col-md-8">                                           
    <input type="text" name="regular" class="form-control" ng-model="item.type">
  </div>
  <br><br>
</div>
```

Controller

```
  $scope.data = [
    { "id": "3", "name": "abacus", "type": "math device" },
    { "id": "4", "name": "beaker", "type": "science device" }
  ];
```

Comment: @CALLODACITY Thanks this solved my question but how about if my json value is inside an array? how will I solve this?

Comment: @bleykFaust what do you mean inside an array? Isn't it already inside an array `[{ "id": "3", ...}, {...}]`?

Comment: @CALLODACITY, Actually, I got the values of that JSON through an API and then pass the values inside an array. Btw, can we continue this discussion on chat? I greatly appreciates your help

Comment: @CALLODACITY, When I tried to use this and exchange my code on this the only value that is displayed and repeated is the first one the second one is not being repeated

Comment: @bleykFaust did you look at the jsfiddle I linked? that's a fully working angular app. Just re-write your code to resemble that and it will work fine.

Comment: I tried but I can only display the first set of data and it is the one repeating @CALLODACITY

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this (assuming `json` is defined on scope and contains your data)

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" ng-repeat-start="item in json">
            ID:
        </label>                                                  
        <div class="col-md-8">                                           
            <input type="text" name="regular" class="form-control" ng-model="item.id">
        </div>
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
            Name:
        </label>                                                  
        <div class="col-md-8">                                           
            <input type="text" name="regular" class="form-control" ng-model="item.name">
        </div>
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
            Type:
        </label>                                                  
        <div class="col-md-8">                                           
            <input type="text" name="regular" class="form-control" ng-model="item.type">
        </div>
            <br><br ng-repeat-end>
</div>
```

Comment: how can I define that json inside a scope? @e-neko

Comment: Json is not javascript, what you want is transform the json to a javascript object, try JSON.parse(text) where text is a string variable with your json